Java using android studio error: Expecting an elemenn
I'm trying to make an android project where the user enters their name into an editText box and when a button is clicked, the name is printed out on a textView box. But, there is an error in my code: Expecting an element. The same error is there for 5 different lines of code:
1.TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
2.EditText inputText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
3.Button toastbutton = findViewById(R.id.button3);
4.toastbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
5.public void onClick(View v){
I double checked the code and I rebuilt it but, still no result.
The whole code: ```
package com.example.buttontoast

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        EditText inputText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

       Button toastbutton = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        toastbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                TextView.setText("hi" + inputText.getText());
            }
    }


}

}




Likely the error is on another line; please post the entire file (and ideally, the complete text of the error, if there's more to it).

Replace: TextView.setText("hi" + inputText.getText()); to textview.setText("hi" + inputText.getText());

I tried it but there doesnt seem to be a difference

ok, so could you please provide please the xml file and error log, It is not obvious what exactly went wrong.

Your code has one missing import R.
It looks like this
import com.example.R;

